Tkinter: Changing font-size depending on the screen
I'm trying to find a formula to scale a font-size of a button to preserve all proportions.
At first I tried it to scale my widgets which worked. I use the following notations to illustrate my way:

With the last two formulars for both screens I can get the amount of pixels depending on the lenght l_x, l'_x given with

and to preserve the ratio from the first screen on the second screen I have to consider

With formulars (1),(2) and (3) I get the new relation for P_l_x' given by

and in analogy I get the same result in the vertical direction given by

With that knowledge I could get a propper scaling for my used widgets in the following code:
import tkinter as tk
from screeninfo import get_monitors

# First monitor informations with a display resolution of 1920x1080
DPI_b = 102.23899371069182 # dots per inch
b = 477 # in mm

DPI_h = 102.35820895522387 # dots per inch
h = 268 # in mm

# Second monitor informations
monitors = get_monitors()
monitor = monitors[0]
b_ = monitor.width_mm
h_ = monitor.height_mm

#print(b_, h_)

P_b_ = monitor.width
P_h_ = monitor.height
DPI_b_ = P_b_ / b_ * 2.54*10
DPI_h_ = P_h_ / h_ * 2.54*10

#print(DPI_b_, DPI_h_)

A_b = DPI_b_/DPI_b
B_b = b_/b
A_h = DPI_h_/DPI_h
B_h = h_/h

print(A_b, B_b, A_h, B_h)


root = tk.Tk()
formatierung = str(int(1370*A_b*B_b)) + 'x' + str(int(120*A_h*B_h))
print(formatierung)
root.geometry(formatierung)
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

print(screen_width, screen_height)

for i in range(8):
    button = tk.Button(master = root, font=('Arial', int(12*screen_height*screen_width/(1080*1920))), text = 'Bestaetigen fuer ' + str(i+1))
    button.place(x = int((10+170*i)*A_b*B_b), y = int(10*A_h*B_h), width = int(160*A_b*B_b), height = int(32*A_h*B_h))
    
for i in range(8):
    button = tk.Button(master = root, font=('Arial', int(12*screen_height*screen_width/(1080*1920))), text = 'Bestaetigen fuer ' + str(i+9))
    button.place(x = int((10+170*i)*A_b*B_b), y = int(60*A_h*B_h), width = int(160*A_b*B_b), height = int(32*A_h*B_h))

root.mainloop()

From here I tested different display resolutions. I noticed the following:
1.) The buttons are scalled propperly.
2.) The font-size seems to be wrong adjusted.
As far I know font-size in tkinter has the unit pt which is defined by the height of a letter and by changing the pt the width is proportionaly adjusted. But no matter what I have tried so far, e.g
int(12 * screen_height * screen_width/(1080*1920))
I always got examples of display resolutions where the letters were too big (or small) on the widgets.
So what dependencies are there really to get a propper value for pt on the other screen?

Have you tried using a monospaced font ?

No and that is the first time I hear about it. How can this help me?

@hallo007 I am not sure if it is useful, but as far as l know you can set the font size in pixels by setting negative values, e.g. font=(“Name”, -15) should create a font of size 15 pixels.

It behaves similar like to my other attempts: For some display resolutions the letters are too big. Anyway I found annother way to get the best font-size. The principle is to compare the used pixels of the string in my button and the used pixels of the wohle button. For my screen it is explicit: 141 pixels for the string (font 'Arial' with 12pt) and 160 pixels for the whole button. Then I consider the ratio 141/160. With the formula for P_l_x' I can calculate the pixels for the other screen. With a while loop for k as font-size I search the best rational approximation for ratio. See my answer.

My approximation solution:
import tkinter as tk
from screeninfo import get_monitors

# First monitor informations
DPI_b = 102.23899371069182 # dots per inch
b = 477 # in mm

DPI_h = 102.35820895522387 # dots per inch
h = 268 # in mm

# Second monitor informations
monitors = get_monitors()
monitor = monitors[0]
b_ = monitor.width_mm
h_ = monitor.height_mm

#print(b_, h_)

P_b_ = monitor.width
P_h_ = monitor.height
DPI_b_ = P_b_ / b_ * 2.54*10
DPI_h_ = P_h_ / h_ * 2.54*10

#print(DPI_b_, DPI_h_)

A_b = DPI_b_/DPI_b
B_b = b_/b
A_h = DPI_h_/DPI_h
B_h = h_/h

print(A_b, B_b, A_h, B_h)


root = tk.Tk()
formatierung = str(int(1370*A_b*B_b)) + 'x' + str(int(120*A_h*B_h))
print(formatierung)
root.geometry(formatierung)
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> new <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
# Find the best font size k
ratio = 141/160 # 141 used pixels for "text = 'Bestaetigen fuer ' + str(0)", 160 used pixels for whole button
k = 0
button = tk.Button(master = root, font=('Arial', k+1), text = 'Bestaetigen fuer ' + str(0))
pixel_aktuell = button.winfo_reqwidth()
pixel_breite = int(160*A_b*B_b)
error = abs(ratio-pixel_aktuell/pixel_breite)
E = [error]
k = 1
button = tk.Button(master = root, font=('Arial', k+1), text = 'Bestaetigen fuer ' + str(0))
pixel_aktuell = button.winfo_reqwidth()
pixel_breite = int(160*A_b*B_b)
error = abs(ratio-pixel_aktuell/pixel_breite)
E.append(error)
while E[k-1] >= E[k]:
    k += 1
    button = tk.Button(master = root, font=('Arial', k+1), text = 'Bestaetigen fuer ' + str(0))
    pixel_aktuell = button.winfo_reqwidth()
    pixel_breite = int(160*A_b*B_b)
    error = abs(ratio-pixel_aktuell/pixel_breite)
    E.append(error)
print(k)
    



# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> new <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<


print(screen_width, screen_height)

for i in range(8):
    button = tk.Button(master = root, font=('Arial', k), text = 'Bestaetigen fuer ' + str(i+1))
    button.place(x = int((10+170*i)*A_b*B_b), y = int(10*A_h*B_h), width = int(160*A_b*B_b), height = int(32*A_h*B_h))
    print(button.winfo_reqwidth())
    
for i in range(8):
    button = tk.Button(master = root, font=('Arial', k), text = 'Bestaetigen fuer ' + str(i+9))
    button.place(x = int((10+170*i)*A_b*B_b), y = int(60*A_h*B_h), width = int(160*A_b*B_b), height = int(32*A_h*B_h))
    print(button.winfo_reqwidth())

root.mainloop()


So yes this solution (searching iterative for the right font-size) avoids indeed tkinter. But is there a specific function/method in tkinter which does basically the same as I do?

Yes, instead of all calculation there is root.call('scaling', float)

Yes I also tried it but this hadn't any effect on the scaling of the widgets. I placed it in the beginning of my code before declaring all my widgets but still inside of my tkinter window code.

I think it should be root.call("tk", "scaling", factor) instead.

I tried it in my code which is shown in my question and nothing changed when I was choosing different displays (or resolutions). So all widgets were not scalled.

Has anyone of you tried this with my code?
